# Unable to write over selected text on a input

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, mobile

I'm unable to write over selected text on a input at Android 2.2.1.

The following [example](http://jsfiddle.net/dcardoso/5WT8t/) selects the input text but the `maxlength` property prevents from writing the new value.

If I remove the `maxlength` the new value is concatenated after the previous value.

**Edit:** If I use the `click` event instead of `keyup` the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/dcardoso/TCqsv/) works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$( '#current1' ).keyup( function(e) {
    $( '#current2' ).focus();
    $( '#current2' ).selectRange( 0, 1 );
});

$.fn.selectRange = function(start, end) {
    var e = document.getElementById($(this).attr('id')); // I don't know why... but $(this) don't want to work today :-/
    if (!e) return;
    else if (e.setSelectionRange) { e.focus(); e.setSelectionRange(start, end); } /* WebKit */
    else if (e.createTextRange) { var range = e.createTextRange(); range.collapse(true); range.moveEnd('character', end); range.moveStart('character', start); range.select(); } /* IE */
    else if (e.selectionStart) { e.selectionStart = start; e.selectionEnd = end; }
};
```

Comment: Happens the same behavior, it selects the text but prevents from writing on it.

Comment: With which version of Android have you tried? The code works fine on most of mobile OS with exception of Android 2.*

Comment: This issue only happens on Android version 2.*